# How to Use userAgent to detect mobile device

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Can anyone help me with this.

I would like to detect device such as Iphone, BB, andriod and browser  to apply their specific css to make it liquefied or adjust to their resolution.

Does andriod and Iphone have difference resolution issue or css problem when it comes to mobile browser because i plan to use same css for those 2 because i know they are using the same browser safari as default.

Comment: I think you have resolution issues is you need a website will come 100% on every device.

Comment: yah im using % on width and height on my site. but i want to make the site look different on mobile. just like Facebook it has its mobile version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use http://www.php.net/get_browser and check for `isMobileDevice` field. It might help only, of course, if the path to `browscap.ini` is set up in php.ini. If not, you can use php classes like https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap

Comment: oh cool this one is in PHP. tried it and it works but one prob is if in mobile they installed a different browser. i would like to be specific in the device so that its would be organize

Comment: @Bert It checks the browser by the User-Agent string submitted with every request. When browser does not send the identification in UA you can not detect it even with javascript. Only, probably, taking into account the screen resolution. But you do not need to know what kind of device it is, only if it is mobile or not.

Comment: yes i tried the code. using it to detect device then i store in a variable $css_iphone =".css" the CSS link so adapt on different device. im also using media queries for this one

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example in javascript:

```
var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);

if (isMobile) {
   // User-Agent is IPhone, IPod, IPad, Android or BlackBerry
}
```

To check for a specific User-Agent string you can do:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) {
   // The User-Agent is iPhone
}
```

Comment: oh let me try that one.. so it will be in javascript? if(isMobile=='iPhone')

Comment: @Bert - Yes it's javascript and you check it like: `if(isMobile) { // doSomething here }`. To check for just IPhone you could do: `if(navigator.userAgent == 'IPhone')`

Comment: yah i tried it it works. i try to use document.getElementById('id').classList.add('class');
document.getElementById('id').classList.remove('class');
to test. i might use jquery for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;  user-scalable=0;" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"/>
<meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on" />


use this code on your website under <header> tag.
```

---

Here is the code for the mobile device detection.

```
 function isMobile() {

// Check the server headers to see if they're mobile friendly
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE"])) {
    return true;
}

// If the http_accept header supports wap then it's a mobile too
if(preg_match("/wap\.|\.wap/i",$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"])) {
    return true;
}

// Still no luck? Let's have a look at the user agent on the browser. If it contains
// any of the following, it's probably a mobile device. Kappow!
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){
    $user_agents = array("midp", "j2me", "avantg", "docomo", "novarra", "palmos", "palmsource", "240x320", "opwv", "chtml", "pda", "windows\ ce", "mmp\/", "blackberry", "mib\/", "symbian", "wireless", "nokia", "hand", "mobi", "phone", "cdm", "up\.b", "audio", "SIE\-", "SEC\-", "samsung", "HTC", "mot\-", "mitsu", "sagem", "sony", "alcatel", "lg", "erics", "vx", "NEC", "philips", "mmm", "xx", "panasonic", "sharp", "wap", "sch", "rover", "pocket", "benq", "java", "pt", "pg", "vox", "amoi", "bird", "compal", "kg", "voda", "sany", "kdd", "dbt", "sendo", "sgh", "gradi", "jb", "\d\d\di", "moto");
    foreach($user_agents as $user_string){
        if(preg_match("/".$user_string."/i",$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

// Let's NOT return "mobile" if it's an iPhone, because the iPhone can render normal pages quite well.
if(preg_match("/iphone/i",$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) {
    return false;
}

// None of the above? Then it's probably not a mobile device.
return false;
}
    if (isMobile()) {
   header("location:$mobile");
  // if the function returned true, it's a mobile.
  //echo "mobile"; // delete this line in your code, and uncomment the next line
 // header('Location: http://www.yoursite.mobi/'); // let's redirect the page to   the mobile site

   }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i search over the net and saw that viewport is to control layout on mobile device. thanks this one is what is missed..

Comment: i really don't like `Let's NOT return "mobile" if it's an iPhone`

Answer (score 0):

take a look here : http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html
and here : http://www.mobile-phone-specs.com/user-agent-browser/0/

There are lists of almost all user agent strings for you.
.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Media Queries to identify the different devices (actually the different device features like device-width, dpi, etc)

For the CSS, you can have different options like having separate CSS for each type of device OR having a fluid design which would mean having the same CSS scale for different device sizes. The 2nd approach is slightly complex to design, but is much more flexible from new devices that may come up in future..

Comment: yes im using CSS media queries for resolution for 1024X768 and lower. im thinking of making the same look as of in the computer/laptop with the IPAD or any 10.1 device.i will also apply this when i have the condition to detect each device.

Comment: That is the best approach to have when you think of realistically...I mean each year with so many devices coming in the amrket, rather than having to create separate CSS for each of the devices, you can use fluid/responsive design and let the layout scale itself according to the device on which it is viewed on..

Comment: i see. your absolutely correct. due to different resolution of device which make it harder for the web developer to edit css file to adapt to device its better to use fluid style for future use.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
$mobile= stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'mob');
```

It works almost every time.

Javascript

```
var mobile= navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'mob');
```

-1 if not mobile; any other value if mobile

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))

header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');

?>
```