# PHP headers from a mobile phone

Tags: php, android, ios

I need to find a way that PHP checks in the headers or somewhere to confirm that a POST request is sent from a mobile phone (android or ios)

Comment: Check the useragent. http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306774/how-to-use-useragent-to-detect-mobile-device

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Answer (score 0):

You can read the `HTTP User-Agent` header. There are a lot of PHP libraries that can read the header to detect what browser is being used as well as what it's capabilities are. A couple of examples are [php-mobile-detect](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) and [Mobile-Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/). PHP also includes the `get_browser()` function that you can use to look up the capabilities of the User_Agent.

Answer (score 0):

A quick simple solution would be by using the `user agent`

```
if($_POST) {
    $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    if(stripos($ua,'android') !== false) {
         $Android = true;
    }
}
```