# If screen size is mobile change some while loop settings

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php

include 'dbconnect.php';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM champions") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1' width='100%' >"; 
echo "<tr>";  
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    if($i++%12 == 0) echo '</tr><tr>';
    $id = $row[0];
    $name = $row[21];
    $image = $row[2];
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href=$name/?id=$id>";
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" />';   
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</td>";


   }  
 echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";          

?>
```

I'm trying to make this if it's a mobile screen to change value of %12 to %3 so only 3 images display in a row, as a mobile screen is smaller than usual size screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look into a grid system, like Bootstrap. getbootstrap.com. It will save you tons of time in the long run.

Comment: Or better yet, flex boxes.  Best.  Layout.  System.  EVER.  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I just heard of flex yesterday...OMG, so awesome. Can't wait for a new project to give it a whirl.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap @LeeSalminen this is nothing to do with it, I'll check that out Dan

Comment: My suggestion would be to change the table to a `ul > li` layout, float the `li`s and set the width of the `li`s based on the device's width using media queries in the CSS.  No need to do this on the server-side.

Comment: See my full answer below, there are some good ways to detect a mobile device in PHP.

Comment: Also, if using Bootstrap, you can wrap a table in `.table-responsive` div.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has many libraries to help detect mobile browsers, try:

[How to Use userAgent to detect mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306774/how-to-use-useragent-to-detect-mobile-device)

Answer (score 0):

Test the header informations, this is not 100% exact but you can set your value if you match android, iOS or wphone ;)

I can't post code with my smartphone but you can get many examples on Google ;)