# Display different content or redirect user by OS(Android or iOS) in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, global-variables

I want to redirect user to a different site or display different content based on the OS they are using, i know how to do this if the plugin have setting to `shorcodes`, but i don't know how to do this by php plugin(that don't have settings).
**Let me be more clear, I want to insert the user OS to a global variable by plugin.**
The redirect phase will be done later. 
Someone knows how to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use userAgent to detect mobile device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306774/how-to-use-useragent-to-detect-mobile-device)

Comment: i want use a plugin that include  shotcodes and not php.

Comment: In that case, this question is off topic.

Comment: Let me be more clear, I want to insert the user OS to a global variable.

Comment: or something like - https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-user-agent-displayer/ but without comment, just a shortcode that have the user agent data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php funtion  `get_browser()`  for checking device and browser

Comment: i want use a plugin that include shotcodes and not php, simple plugin that have shortcodes for OS.

Comment: you shuold write a plugin. or search for  plugin that have this functionality

Comment: Let me be more clear, I want to insert the user OS to a global variable by plugin.

Comment: or something like - https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-user-agent-displayer/ but without comment, just a shortcode that have the user agent data.