# Change link depending on Mobile and Tablet in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

As I cloak my Links for Affiliate Programs, I would now also like to add the extra to change the link if the user is on Mobile or Tablet, which will be a different despite from the Desktop or as the Code below.

```
<php
$path = array(
"NameoftheSiteDesktop" => "link",
"NameoftheSiteTablet" => "link",
"NameoftheSiteMobile" => "link",
);

if (array_key_exists($_GET["id"], $path))
header("Location: " .$path[$_GET["id"]]);
?>
```

With the htaccess ;

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainname.com$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^go/([/_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ links.php?id=$1
```

So the link will look like http://domainname.com/go/Nameofthesite

The question I ask myself now is: how am I supposed to change this without JavaScript, but with PHP or even better in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this library

http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

OR

javascript way

```
var mobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/);

if(mobile) {
    alert('this is mobile');
}
else{
    console.log(navigator.userAgent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use php user agent to detect mobile browser
[detect mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306774/how-to-use-useragent-to-detect-mobile-device)

I have given one sample link you could search many other on google for detecting mobile browser in php using user agent